# Search RSS Feed in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a table view which loads an RSS feed.  I know how to add a search bar but i'm not sure how to actually search the table view.  I know how to search a table view if I load it with an array but I can't figure out how to search this table view because the data is from a feed.

Here is my code:

```
#import "GRSStoreViewController.h"
#import "RSSChannel.h"
#import "RSSItem.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "DTCustomColoredAccessory.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#import "TWTSideMenuViewController.h"
#import "UIImage+ImageEffects.h"

@implementation GRSStoreViewController
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
}
@synthesize webViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // UIImage *normalBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuBackground.png"];
    // UIImage *effectImage = [normalBackground applyDarkEffect];
    // UIImageView *blurredBackground = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    // blurredBackground.image = effectImage;

    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundBlurredDarkened.png"]];

    UIBarButtonItem *openItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openButtonPressed)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = openItem;

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:background];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    self.title = @"Store";

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
    swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];

    [[SVProgressHUD appearance]setHudBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[SVProgressHUD appearance]setHudForegroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
    // [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading" maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
}

- (IBAction)swipeRight:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [self.sideMenuViewController openMenuAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)openButtonPressed
{
    [self.sideMenuViewController openMenuAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"%@ found a %@ element", self, elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"channel"])
    {
        // If the parser saw a channel, create new instance, store in our ivar
        channel = [[RSSChannel alloc]init];

        // Give the channel object a pointer back to ourselves for later
        [channel setParentParserDelegate:self];

        // Set the parser's delegate to the channel object
        [parser setDelegate:channel];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // return 0;
    NSLog(@"channel items %d", [[channel items]count]);
    return [[channel items]count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // return nil;
    // UIImage *normalBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuBackground.png"];
    // UIImage *effectImage = [normalBackground applyDarkEffect];
    // UIImageView *blurredBackground = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    // blurredBackground.image = effectImage;

    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundBlurredDarkened.png"]];

    tableView.backgroundView = background;

    // UIColor *kfbBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0/255.0f green:77.0/255.0f blue:139.0/255.0f alpha:1];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }
    RSSItem *item = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *pubDate = [formatter dateFromString:[item date]];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:pubDate];
    NSLog(@"Date String: %@", dateString);

    NSURL *imageLink = [NSURL URLWithString:[item imageURL]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageLink];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

    [[cell textLabel]setText:[item title]];

    NSLog(@"Date: %@", [item date]);

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:20.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    // tableView.backgroundView = blurredBackground;

    DTCustomColoredAccessory *accessory = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:cell.textLabel.textColor];
    // accessory.highlightedColor = kfbBlue;
    cell.accessoryView =accessory;

    return cell;
}

- (void)fetchEntries
{
    // Create a new data container for the stuff that comes back from the service
    xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    // Construct a URL that will ask the service for what you want -
    // note we can concatenate literal strings together on multiple lines in this way - this results in a single NSString instance
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://littleheart.bigcartel.com/products.rss"];

    // Put that URL into an NSURLRequest
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Create a connection that will exchange this request for data from the URL
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self)
    {
        [self fetchEntries];
    }

    return self;
}

// This method will be called several times as the data arrives
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Add the incoming chunk of data to the container we are keeping
    // The data always comes in the correct order
    [xmlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
    /* We are just checking to make sure we are getting the XML
     NSString *xmlCheck = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"xmlCheck = %@", xmlCheck);*/

    // [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    // Create the parser object with the data received from the web service
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];

    // Give it a delegate
    [parser setDelegate:self];

    //Tell it to start parsing - the document will be parsed and the delegate of NSXMLParser will get all of its delegate messages sent to it before this line finishes execution - it is blocking
    [parser parse];

    // Get rid of the XML data as we no longer need it
    xmlData = nil;

    // Reload the table.. for now, the table will be empty
    [[self tableView]reloadData];

    NSLog(@"%@\n %@\n %@\n", channel, [channel title], [channel infoString]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Release the connection object, we're done with it
    connection = nil;

    // Release the xmlData object, we're done with it
    xmlData = nil;

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    // Grab the description of the error object passed to us
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fetch failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];

    // Create and show an alert view with this error displayed
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [av show];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

    // Push the web view controller onto the navigation stack - this implicitly creates the web view controller's view the first time through
    // [[self navigationController]pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

    // Grab the selected item
    RSSItem *entry = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSLog(@"Channel Items: %@", [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);

    // Construct a URL with the link string of the item
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

    NSLog(@"Link: %@", [entry link]);

    // Construct a request object with that URL
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);

    // Load the request into the web view
    [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:req];
    webViewController.hackyURL = url;
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", req);

    // Set the title of the web view controller's navigation item
    // [[webViewController navigationItem]setTitle:[entry title]];

    NSLog(@"Title: %@", [entry title]);

    NSLog(@"Pub Date: %@", [entry date]);

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

@end
```

I've tried something like this but it doesn't alter the table view.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

{
    BOOL itemFound = NO;
    NSString *searchText = [searchBar text];

```
for (int i = 0; [[channel items]count] < i; i++)
{
    RSSItem *item = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:i];
    // NSMutableArray *searchItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *itemTitle = [item title];
    NSRange titleRange = [itemTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    [[channel items]removeAllObjects];

    if (titleRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        itemFound = YES;
        // [searchItems addObject:item];
        // [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:searchItems withRowAnimation:YES];
        [[channel items]addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        break;
    }
}

if (itemFound == NO)
{
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No Matches Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [av show];
}

[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do the search in table view because the cells which are not visible on the screen mostly do not contain data (they are put in a reusable pool) . You have to do a search in your data source:

```
[channel items]
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It helps but I'm not entirely sure how to go about searching channel items and reloading the table view to only show the results.

Comment: Have a look on NSPredictate, you can filter array with predicate and save it to another array. There is a few different ways to display it for example you can use flag (isSearch) and if it's try you can use [chanels item] in the tableView delegate methods but if its false use your array returned by predicate.

Comment: See what I've tried.  I'm trying it this way because I have done something similar when searching map annotation.